# Use $regex to match in both document and $lookup result in mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I'm working on searching function that regex match the search input to the company's name , owner name and owner email.My Company and user collection are like this.

Companys collection

```
{
    _id: ObjectId('6421204b937b21001d44cadf'),
    name: 'test',
    is_delete: false,
    active: true
    owners_id: ObjectId('641c021cda143c01b05c370a'),
}
```

Users collection (owner)

```
{
    _id: ObjectId('641c021cda143c01b05c370a'),
    name: 'test_user',
}
```

Here's my current query ( input is 'test' )

```
 companys.aggregate(
[
  {
    '$match': {
      '$and': [
        {
          is_delete: false,
          active: true
        }
      ],
      '$or': [
        {
          name: {
            '$regex': '.*test.*',
            '$options': 'i'
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    '$lookup': {
      from: 'users',
      as: 'owner_user',
      let: {
        users_id: '$owners_id'
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          '$match': {
            '$expr': {
              '$and': [
                {
                  '$eq': [
                    '$_id',
                    '$$users_id'
                  ]
                }
              ]
            },
            '$or': [
              {
                name: {
                  '$regex': '.*test.*',
                  '$options': 'i'
                }
              },
              {
                email: {
                  '$regex': '.*test.*',
                  '$options': 'i'
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    '$unwind': '$owner_user'
  },
  {
    '$sort': {
      _id: -1
    }
  },
  {
    '$facet': {
      metadata: [
        {
          '$count': 'total'
        },
        {
          '$addFields': {
            page: 1
          }
        }
      ],
      data: [
        {
          '$skip': 0
        },
        {
          '$limit': 10
        }
      ]
    }
  }
],
{
  
}
)
```

The Problem from above is the results are have to had word 'test' in company's name and owner's name in order to become result.If search input is 'us' which match regx in owner's name but not in company's name the result will be empty array

Is there any way to make the query show results if regex match either company's name , owner's name or owner's email to become results?

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the $or array in your $match stage to include conditions for matching the owner name and email and the company name.

```
companys.aggregate([
  {
    '$match': {
      '$and': [
        { is_delete: false, active: true },
        {
          '$or': [
            { name: { '$regex': '.*test.*', '$options': 'i' } },
            { 'owner_user.name': { '$regex': '.*test.*', '$options': 'i' } },
            { 'owner_user.email': { '$regex': '.*test.*', '$options': 'i' } }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
//More code
]);
```